# Track envelope status in salesforce using envelope external source Id via API

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign package in my org. By using a custom buttom I am able to send a record for docusign approval. In this i set Source Id as record Id and track the status in a custom field on that record. But now I m using Docusign SOAP API and sending a record for docusign via Apex. But now I am unable to set envelope external source id in code and therefore status is not getting updated in that record.
Please reply if anyone has any idea how to set source id via apex and track status?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create an envelope custom field in your API call for the recordID and pass that through in your APEX code. The DocuSign for Salesforce manage package does this automatically and that's how the data gets written back to the correct records using Connect.

Create the envelope custom field in DocuSign and then add the CustomField Schema Type to your API call and populate it with the source ID. Then in Connect under the DocuSign Status Object map that Custom Field back to either the five out of the box objects or your custom object.